# Need RegEx code to remove a dash at the end of a zipcode unless there are numbers after the dash

Tags: java, regex

I have zipcodes that are 5 digits, and I have zipcodes that are 9 digits with a dash in between.

The problem is that the 5 digit zip codes have a dash at the end, and I would like to remove the dash only if the zipcodes aren't 9 digit zipcodes.

Additional clarification: So I have zipcodes in the following formats: #####- and #####-####. I'd like to change it to ##### and #####-####

Comment: Do you have other zip codes with 6 characters beside 5 digits and dash? If not then why not just check if length is 6 and if last character is dash, and then substring it to 5 characters?

Comment: The data is sometimes bad and will have 6 numbers because someone typed it in incorrectly. We have data quality tools that will not catch the bad data if we remove the last number, so I wanted to make sure that it was 5 numbers then a dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(zipCode.endsWith("-")) {  
    // remove '-' 

}
```

Comment: +1 No need to use a regex when simple string ops can be substituted

Answer (score 1):

```
if (postcode.length() == 6)
        postcode = postcode.substring(0,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex:

```
(?<=^[0-9]{5})(-)(?=$)
```

working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/oO1hG2

java code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=^[0-9]{5})(-)(?=$)", "");
```

Comment: That's an awesome website that you linked me to, I had no idea that existed. Thanks a lot, it seems very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(\\d{5})-?");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4})-?(\\d{5})");

Matcher matcher = p1.matcher(zipCode);
String parsed;
if (matcher.find()) {
   parsed = matcher.group(1);
} else {
   matcher = p2.matcher(zipCode);
   if (matcher.find()) {
      parsed = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this:

```
if(zipcode.matches("\\d{5}-") //if zipcode is five digits (\d{5}) followed by a hyphen (-)...
{
    zipcode = zipcode.substring(0, zipcode.length() - 1); //...make zipcode equal itself minus the last character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-9]{5})\-$
```

As example ([regex example](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html%5E%28%5B0-9%5D%7B5%7D%29/-%24)), matches for `09090-` will be:

```
0: [0,6] 09090-
1: [0,5] 09090
```

you can just replace it with matches

```
/^([0-9]{5})[\-][0-9]{4}$/   //skip replacement.
```